# Import multiple HTML files in the html format into Excel

Tags: html, excel

I have multiple seperate HTML files and I want to import the HTML format of each one in a different cell of a single column in MS Excel.

So, in the end I want a single column containing all the seperate raw HTML files.

I searched on multiple forums but haven't found anything relevant.
Thank you in advance